# How to display count of submitted radio button values using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, group-by, count

I am trying to display the total number of submitted radio button value, in my previous form, there is a choice between "Male", "Female" for user to choose and submit, and I have a database to store the values (`radiob`).

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "test";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT radiob FROM playertest";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo  $row["radiob"] . "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
```

I have my code above only display all the items in the database under radiob,

```
Male
Male
Female
```

Is there anyway that I can display it with the total count?
Would want it to look like:

```
Male: 2
Female: 1
```

Comment: Could you please share the table details alone with some sample data

Comment: `"SELECT count(id) as total, radiob FROM playertest GROUP BY radiob ";` assuming you have a field `id`

Comment: I only have 2 field, one is name, one is gender. Sorry I am pretty new to PHP and trying to play around with PHP

Example of the database would be
    James  Male
    John  Male
    Mary Female
    ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an Aggragage query with count

```
"SELECT count(id) as total, radiob FROM playertest GROUP BY radiob ";
```

I suggest adding an Auto Increment ID field as the primary key if you don't already have it.

This is known as a surrogate key in the Database world, and as your table grows you will really want to have one so you can properly refer to a row in other queries.

if you don't like that you can do

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $rows = [];
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         $rows[] =  $row["radiob"];
    }
}

$totals = array_count_values($rows);
```

> array_count_values() returns an array using the values of array as keys and their frequency in array as values. 
>   http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php

SO $rows should be like this

```
['male','male', 'female']
```

And array_count_values will give you this

```
['male' => 2, 'female' => 1]
```

Now if you want rows to contain more data such as

```
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     $rows[] =  $row;  //assume row is ['name'=>'foo', 'radiob' => 'male']
  }
```

You can first do `array_column` such as ( to unwrap it )

```
  $totals = array_count_values(array_column($rows, 'radiob'));
```

> array_column() returns the values from a single column of the input, identified by the column_key. Optionally, an index_key may be provided to index the values in the returned array by the values from the index_key column of the input array. 
>   http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php

In summery the best way is to Aggregate it using the query, but you may have other data besides this you need ( such as name ), in that case do the second method.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution. There are various ways to do it and I am not 100% certain of the output you want. But this might get you started. I added variables to hold the integer values of the male/female counts. I put them in an array with a key value that matches the values in your database. Then in each loop, the value is incremented on the total of the array element matching the DB row value. At the end I echo the two totals.

```
$sql = "SELECT radiob FROM playertest";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$array[ 'Male' => 0, 'Female' => 0 ];    

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $array[$row["radiob"]]++;
        echo  $row["radiob"] . "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
echo "Male {$array['Male']}\n";
echo "Female {$array['Female']}\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

You should modify the code using a group by sentence to look like this

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "test";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT radiob,COUNT(*) as total FROM `playertest` group by radiob";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo  $row["radiob"] . ": ".$row["total"]."<br>";
    }
} else {
echo "0 results";}
$conn->close();
?>
```